# Account is showing up twice in Network Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

For some reason User Experience is showing up twice on my [Network Profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/2d20e82f-5a87-48bf-bbef-92b64684cacd?tab=accounts), as if I had two accounts.

[image: Double trouble]

This is significantly & detrimentally impacting my user experience. ;)

I only signed up a couple of days ago as I saw an interesting question via the main stackexchange site.

Any clues as to why this is happening. I'm sure I didn't sign up twice.

Comment: Bizarre... Obviously, you're destined for greatness here - better start posting stuff!

Comment: I logged out completely (all accounts) and then logged in on another computer. Still there. Not that it bothers me greatly. @Shog9 - You're too kind. Regrettably I don't even know what 'user experience' is so I'm not sure about how the greatness prophecy will turn out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice catch.  This was caused by a deploy glitch a couple days ago.  All accounts that were affected have been cleaned up.

Comment: Yep, seems to have worked. Thanks a lot.